# Install Scala on Raspberry Pi2 (OS Arch Linux)

Tags: scala, installation, raspberry-pi2

Who knows, how to install latest version of scala on Raspberry Pi2 with Arch Linux OS ? I couldn't find any clear information on this topic. Please, help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Scala is program compiled into bytecode. Not so long time ago, it was written in Java, now it is ported to Scala itself.

The only thing you need is Java in version at least of 6.

Scala is just a jar artifact.

I've googled for you an example tutorial, how it would look like if you use maven to download Scala as dependency in a project and compile your code:

http://stuq.nl/weblog/2008-11-26/4-steps-to-add-scala-to-your-maven-java-projects